# Inconsistency of numeric output of dplyr and base R

Tags: r, dplyr

Take the following piece of code:

```
library(dplyr)

x <- c(8.98)
t <- tibble(x)

t %>% 
  mutate(y = map_dbl(1:1, ~ slice(t,.x) %>% pull(.,x) %>% sqrt())) %>% 
  mutate(across(2,round,3))
```

Its output is:

```
# A tibble: 1 × 2
      x     y
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  8.98  3.00
```

However, the code `round(sqrt(8.98),3)` produces `2.997`, while, in the tibble, the result is `3.00`.

Should not both results be *exactly* the same? Is this a bug or something we should be expecting?

Comment: According to the answer of above question  you can set `options(pillar.sigfig = 4)`

Comment: Thanks! It is a bit annoying that one should care about significant digits when data.frames manage those automatically.